# Vertical spacing inside beamer \titlepage, got "Token not allowed in a PDF string..."?

Tags: beamer, spacing, hyperref, titles

I'm trying to separate (with a vertical spacing) the word "Me" from "Prof: My professor", basically putting the latter on a new line. This works fine, but I've got a warning:

> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
>   (hyperref) removing `\vskip' on input line 31.

Should I care? How can I remove the warning, mantaining the vertical spacing?

```
% titlepage settings
\title[My title]{My long title}
\author[Me]{Me \vskip25pt \footnotesize Prof: My professor}
\institute{University of Foo\\My title}
\date{18 luglio 2013}
```

Comment: `Me\texorpdfstring{\vspace{25pt}\footnotesize}{} Prof: My prof` might do

Comment: @egreg works fine, please answer the question, I'll accept it. Btw why should i use `\texorpdfstring`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some tokens are not allowed in bookmarks: a `\vspace` command doesn't make sense in them, for instance, since bookmarks are one line only.

For coping with this problem `hyperref` provides `\texorpdfstring` that takes two arguments: the first one is for what you want TeX to typeset, the second one a substitute for the bookmark.

So

```
\author{Me\texorpdfstring{\\[25pt]\footnotesize}{}Prof: My professor}
```

should do what you want.

Another use case would be if a title contains a math formula, say

```
\section{A proof that $\pi$ is rational}
```

which would confuse the bookmarks; in that case you can type

```
\section{A proof that \texorpdfstring{$\pi$}{pi} is rational}
```

so you give a cheap substitute for the bookmark.

Comment: `π` is available in bookmarks with `hyperref` option `unicode` or `pdfencoding=auto`: `\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}...\texorpdfstring{$\pi$}{\textpi}`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks. With `beamer` one probably has to use `\hypersetup{pdfencoding=auto}` or say `hyperref={pdfencoding=auto}` in the `\documentclass` options.